# Using SharePoint to segregate departments in an intranet site

Tags: sharepoint

I've just created an intranet site for reporting on production figures.  Data capture on the site, and as well as in the report, must be restricted to the logged on user's department, except for certain highly level users that can access all departments.  What are my options for achieving this on a SharePoint based intranet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create different document library for each department and then assign unique permission for each department/document library combination. [Click here for step by step guide](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/how-to-change-document-library-permissions-in-sharepoint/2007-11-20/). If you already have these departments defined as AD or SharePoint groups this will be easy to setup.